# Can't scroll table horizontally on Android phone

Tags: javascript, android, iframe, interactive

I have developed an interactive table in HTML, CSS and js. It's a simple interactive where students can enter text in textarea and check their answers. The interactive is inserted with  inside a course page (in Canvas LMS or Blackboard or Moodle, depending on the course). Everything works fine, except that on Android we can't scroll horizontally to view all the columns of the table (when a large table doesn't fit on screen). It actually works fine on my old Samsung Galaxy 3 but not on newer Android phones.
I know my question and summary of the issue is not quite detailed but I was hoping it's a known issue and you guys have a fix or workaround. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't provided any source code to work with, but my best guess is that the table is being clipped.

Try adding `table {overflow-x: scroll}` in your CSS to provide a horizontal scrollbar when the viewport width is thinner than the `table`'s width.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I will try that. I haven't supplied the code because it's pretty big (it's a template to make all kinds of tables so it's a long boring code).